Can't you use ASIO SSL socket in non-blocking mode?
In ASIO the non SSL socket is of type:
asio::ip::tcp::socket;

Which is a typedef of:
asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>

The SSL socket is a wrapper of an ordinary socket:
asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>;

I'm trying to send a video to a browser that's 2MB large. I try to write the entire 2MB data using socket_type.write_some() — socket_type being one of the two mentioned above. When I use the non-SSL socket_type, the number of bytes return is all of it, all 2 million of them. And I have the typical loop set up, which, if the entire number of bytes aren't written, I write the remainder (as it should be done). And on the browser side it's received successfully, all 2MB.
Now using the SSL socket I try to write 2MB, I invariably get a number of bytes written as 16,384 bytes which I learned is the maximum SSL record size. OK, so not all of it was written, that's fine, I'll simply write the remainder in the next call, and next, and the next until it's all done. I ALWAYS get 16,384 bytes written, despite the fact that the error code returned is WOULD_BLOCK.
If I turn the socket to blocking mode, it works fine. If I place a thread sleep of 100ms between each write call, it works fine.
The only valid conclusion:
The socket is not ready to have more data written to it after it returns WOULD_BLOCK.
But if it returns WOULD_BLOCK, why is the number of bytes written always 16,384? And why would writing again create an error (it seems on both the remote side and the local side) if I try to write more bytes to it too early? The way it should work (I thought) is that if it would block (due to writing too much, say the buffer's full and pending data is waiting to be transmitted), then the number of bytes written might be less, or zero, instead it's invariably 16,384.
It seems non-blocking mode cannot be used with an SSL socket in ASIO, because when you get the message WOULD_BLOCK, there's no way to know when you can write again.

It seems you can't, according to this, it seems it hasn't been fixed.
Excerpt:

This function read the encrypted data from OpenSSL buffer and transmit
it using usual boost write operation. The problem is that the return
of this function is not checked. The amount of the send data by this
function can be less than required (16KB). But the user application is
notified that that write_some function have sent 16+K. This leads to
the unsynchronized state of SSL on both sides. The sender consider it
sends +16KB, but receiver has gotten say only 4KB. Other data are
lost. The user application makes next send skipping the 16KB. And
after some send operation OpenSSL recognize the error state. It
reports the error and boost closes the socket.


That's the whole point of non-blocking operation.  You ask it to write some data and then check back periodically to see if it's done while you do other stuff.  If you want the library to handle that for you use async_write.

@MilesBudnek I can't check back, every single call returns 16,384 bytes written, it writes too much.

I'm not sure I follow.  Are you saying write_some returns 16384 and sets the error code to WOULD_BLOCK in the same call?  Did  you reset the error_code between the calls?  I don't think write_some modifies its value if no error occurs.

@MilesBudnek Yes, that's exactly it. It's not supposed to work like that, right? It doesn't make any sense. Does this have anything to do with OpenSSL? Ultimately the ASIO code is calling SSL_write() Edit: hold on, let me check if resetting the ec does anything.

@MilesBudnek Yep, error code is 0, which is initial state. I call write_some, it returns 16,384 and sets WOULD_BLOCK. The return value is always 16384

An SSL socket is basically a buffered layer over unbuffered I/O. This means that it does not fully behave like a plain TCP socket.
If you try to write more than 16k it will take 16k (max record size) and create a SSL record from it which is stored in the SSL socket for now. It will then try to write this SSL record to the underlying socket.
This writing of the full SSL record to the underlying socket might not succeed immediately, i.e. only part of the record might have been written. As long as not everything is written to the kernel socket buffer, some yet unwritten data from the newly created SSL record will be kept buffered in the SSL object.
As long as there is there are still unwritten parts of the SSL record in the SSL object further calls to SSL_write (which underlines write_some) will just try to deliver the remaining data and not accept new data. That's why the WOULD_BLOCK is returned (which is probably internally translated from the SSL_WANT_WRITE returned by SSL_write).

I have a feeling you're right it's related to this, it seems like SSL message boundaries have been cut off as I remember in Firefox seeing something like invalid SSL record something.

Interestingly, I can write a full 80MB file to a non SSL socket and it returns all bytes written in one call. I thought there would have been a limit or something and that you should call it with smaller sizes. I have a hunch that if I call and try to send 200MB it will probably likewise succeed in one call.

@Zebrafish: How much you can write depends on the size of the socket buffer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213399/tcp-buffer-in-play-while-using-boostasioasync-write.  80MB is kind of unusual large though.

So, coming back to this question, sorry for resurrecting it but I don't know what to do. SSL sockets are unusable in non-blocking mode? There's no documentation about this.
